# Cannot compile RGBdemo 0.7 Linux Mint 17 - undefined reference to symbol 'glOrtho'

Tags: c++, cmake, linux-mint

This is my very first post here. I am trying to compile RGBdemo to test its reconstruction capabilities with kinect.

I have followed these instructions 
[RGBdemo compiling instructions](https://sites.google.com/site/3dreconstructionusingkinect/project-updates/Installation-of-RGB-demo-07-on-Ubuntu-1204?pageUrlChanged=Installation-of-RGB-demo-07-on-Ubuntu-1204)

I was able to follow all the instructions more or less consistently but I stomp at the ending (compiling RGBdemo 0.7). Here is the make code.

```
[ 48%] Built target XnSensorServer
make -f nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Players/CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/build.make nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Players/CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/build'
cd /home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source /home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Players /home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/build /home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/build/nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Players /home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/build/nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Players/CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/build'
make -f nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Players/CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/build.make nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Players/CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/build'
Linking CXX executable ../../../../../../bin/Sample-Players
cd /home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/build/nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Players && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -fPIC -O2 -g -DNDEBUG    CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/signal_catch.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/SceneDrawer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/kbhit.cpp.o  -o ../../../../../../bin/Sample-Players  -L/home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Lib/Linux64 -rdynamic ../../../../../../lib/libOpenNI.so -lglut -lusb-1.0 -ldl ../../../../../../lib/libTinyXml.a -Wl,-rpath,/home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Lib/Linux64:/home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/build/lib 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glOrtho'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/Sample-Players] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/build'
make[1]: *** [nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Players/CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/andre/.RGBDemo-0.7.0-Source/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have not much experience in compiling programs although I have some programming skills.

I have searched extensively how to solve this issue searching for the errors
"reference to symbol 'glOrtho'" and "adding symbols: DSO missing from command line" but I can't find a decent solution that helped me.

For example this case
[Linker error : undefined reference to symbol 'glOrtho'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766420/linker-error-undefined-reference-to-symbol-glortho)
states that I should link an OpenGL library to a certain file. In my case I think it should be main.cpp but I am unable to find it :-(.
Any help is much appreciated.

---

**Update**

Here is the current progress that I was able to achieve in the make

```
Scanning dependencies of target nestk
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/andre/.rgbdemo/build'
make -f nestk/ntk/CMakeFiles/nestk.dir/build.make nestk/ntk/CMakeFiles/nestk.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/andre/.rgbdemo/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/andre/.rgbdemo/build/CMakeFiles 56
[ 59%] Building CXX object nestk/ntk/CMakeFiles/nestk.dir/aruco/board.o
cd /home/andre/.rgbdemo/build/nestk/ntk && /usr/bin/c++   -DHAVE_OPENCV_GREATER_THAN_2_2 -DHAVE_OPENCV_GREATER_THAN_2_3_0 -DNESTK_USE_CUSTOM_OPENNI -DNESTK_USE_EIGEN -DNESTK_USE_FREENECT -DNESTK_USE_GLEW -DNESTK_USE_OPENNI -DNESTK_USE_QT -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -Dnestk_EXPORTS -fPIC -Wall -W -Wno-unused -Wno-sign-compare -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fPIC -I/home/andre/.rgbdemo/build/nestk/deps -I/home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/deps -isystem /usr/include/qt4 -isystem /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/include/qt4/QtSvg -isystem /usr/include/qt4/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt4/QtXml -isystem /usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/deps/include -I/home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/deps/eigen -I/home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/deps/libfreenect/include -I/home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/deps/openni/Include -I/home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Include -I/home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/deps/glew/include -I/home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk -I/home/andre/.rgbdemo/build/nestk    -o CMakeFiles/nestk.dir/aruco/board.o -c /home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/ntk/aruco/board.cpp
In file included from /home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/ntk/geometry/pose_3d.h:23:0,
                 from /home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/ntk/aruco/marker.h:17,
                 from /home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/ntk/aruco/board.h:19,
                 from /home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/ntk/aruco/board.cpp:1:
/home/andre/.rgbdemo/nestk/ntk/core.h:31:38: fatal error: opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp: No such file or directory
 # include "opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp"
                                      ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nestk/ntk/CMakeFiles/nestk.dir/aruco/board.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/andre/.rgbdemo/build'
make[1]: *** [nestk/ntk/CMakeFiles/nestk.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/andre/.rgbdemo/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I will try to find how to correct those directories but I would really apreciate some help on this. Please, I am doing this a bit by trial and error and I know this is not the right way to go. I am not an expert on cmake compilation.

Comment: I'm keeping here the results from my research. Seems that there's a similar issue in this Github post
https://github.com/rgbdemo/rgbdemo/issues/27

Comment: Some progress...
By some sort of miracle I was able to find out that I have to add the "-lGL" in the link.txt files of the /build/nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Boxes/CMakeFiles/Boxes.dir/link.txt file. This has to be done for the Boxes, Players and CircleControl directories. Each one has a link.txt file that must have that extra option between the "lglut" and the "-lusb-1.0" options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove and reinstall OpenCV 2.3.1 with these instructions

http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation-2-3-1/

And after some magic...voilá. It works. I hope that this tips can somehow help anyone.